# Adding an author to a conference paper only for sharing the cost of conference registation

Tags: ethics

Is it unethical to add an author to already finished conference paper just for the purpose of sharing the cost of conference registration?

The added author shares similar research interest but has contributed nothing to the paper in question.

Comment: Yes highly unethical and against authorship rules of any reputable journal / conference.

Comment: If the other person is, in effect, offering you a bribe to be a co-author, then yes, sounds pretty unethical. Your reputation is worth more than the value of the bribe, I think.

Comment: Yes. Could you explain what makes you think it could not be unethical? (This is an honest question, I do not mean to insult you.)

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand the goal of 'sharing the cost' of conference registration and how that is supposed to work. But, no, this is not appropriate.

Comment: How? Isn't conference cost per person? If not you might have been a victim of low quality, predatory conferences...

Comment: @xuq01 Conference attendance is per person but the publication of the paper in a proceeding is per article. It's not a low quality conference.

Comment: @Haque To start with, some labs add members of the lab as co-authors even if only a few were directly involved in a research. Secondly, the cost of conference registration can be almost 80% of some people's salary in some part of the world. This is excluding the cost of attendance.

Comment: I do fully agree that you are right. However, you are asking about the ethics of this practice, not if this practice is usually done or is necessary to have both money for living and for the conference. Your reasons, while they are very good, seem to be unrelated to ethics.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. This is unethical. Any paper author should contribute intellectually to the paper. Even if that is supervision where the supervisor sometimes gives high level guidance.